# make multiple addresses and send from one address to the other

Tags: address, balance

I have a node, and I use GetNewAddress to generate a new receiving address. is it possible to transfer what's in that address to one of the other addresses I have created using GetNewAddress? Each address appears to have an "amount" property. so i assume each address has a balance. so i want to send what's in address A, over to Address B, but from the same wallet.  How would I go about doing this with RPC calls? Forgive me if I don't make sense I am still learning Bitcoin RPC. Thanks so much.

Answer (score 0):

I would try `Rawtransactions` RPC calls such as [`createrawtransaction`](https://developer.bitcoin.org/reference/rpc/createrawtransaction.html), `fundrawtransaction` and `sendrawtransaction`